# How to store html of view file into variable in laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

I just tried below code and it returns nothing.

```
$view = \View::make('users.index', $data)->render();
```

Comment: what use do you have for it?

Comment: check the `users.index` path. everything else seems fine.

Comment: You do not need to assign the return value of View::make to a variable. To check if the view is doing what is supposed to do, just return it from one of your routes and call that route in the browser

Comment: @madalinivascu  works fine now thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try casting your view to string

```
$view = (string)View::make('users.index',$data);
```

to display the view you simply do:

`echo $view`

Comment: OK, Working Fine Now !! Thanks

Comment: For View you 'll need to add 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View; on the top  ...